# Fire function on click only one time each second (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I have a button on a page, that I want to be fired maximum once every second. Meaning that if the user click on it like a madman for five second, it will only be executed five times. I've been googling and searching Stack, with no results. Also tried Alman's throttle/debounce plugin, but doesn't seem to work on clicks.

Comment: do you want to execute that function in each second interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a timer

```
 var clicked = false;
 setInterval(function(){
     clicked = false;
 },5000);

if($('.button').click(function(){
   if(!clicked){
      do job;
      clicked = true;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not disable the button for 1 second in the click event for the button?

```
$('#my_button').click(function() {
    /*
    your logic here
    */

    // disable the button for 1 second
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').delay(1000).removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a throttle that ends the event unless it has been 1 second since the previous click.

```
var clicked = false;
$(element).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (clicked) {
        return;
    }
    clicked = true;
    console.log("Do Stuff");
    setTimeout(function(){
        clicked = false;
    },1000);
});
```

Or you can use a data property to avoid the extra variable:

```
$(element).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).data("clicked")) {
        return;
    }
    $(this).data("clicked",true);
    console.log("Do Stuff");
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(this).data("clicked",false);
    },1000);
}).data("clicked",false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
$(function(){
    var currentTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    $("input:button").click(function(){
        var nowTime = (new Date()).getTime();
        var diff = Math.abs((nowTime - currentTime)/1000);

        if(diff < 1) 
            return;

        currentTime = nowTime;

        // do your stuff
    });
});
```